"No signing certificate" error when testing an iOS app in CI
I have a github action that runs tests against an iOS app. The action looks like this:
name: Tests
on: [pull_request]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Run tests
        run: xcodebuild clean test -workspace "xxx.xcworkspace" -scheme "xxx" -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 12 Pro,OS=latest" | xcpretty && exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}

Recently I have started getting this error preventing CI runs:
    No signing certificate "iOS Development" found: No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "xxxx" with a private key was found.
    No profiles for 'com.xxx.xxx.xxx-iosUITests.xctrunner' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.xxx.xxx.xxxUITests.xctrunner'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.
    No profiles for 'xxx.xxx.xxx' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'xxx.xxx.xxx'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.
    Testing cancelled because the build failed.

I've never had to provide a signing certificate to run tests in CI previously. I get the same error when running xcodebuild locally, but I can run tests fine from inside Xcode. How can I fix CI?

After a lot of trial and error, I found that changing the name of the iPhone I test on fixed things. This is how the action looks now:
name: Test
on: [pull_request]
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: macos-13
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - uses: maxim-lobanov/setup-xcode@v1
      with:
        xcode-version: latest-stable
    - name: Run Tests
      run: xcodebuild test -workspace "xxx.xcworkspace" -scheme "xxx" -destination "name=iPhone 15 Pro" | xcpretty && exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}

But the only change that mattered was changing from an iPhone 12 to an iPhone 15.
